# Are questions about music appreciation pertinent?

Tags: discussion

Since we, as music lovers, are usually familiar with some styles and curious about others, **would it make sense to ask about suggestions on how to best enjoy** music X or Y?

E.g. : Alice is a Bach lover but she'd like to go about listening to Mahler. There are some parts of his 5th that she really likes but she feels she's missing a lot. On the other hand, since she is not classically trained, answers with the `analysis` tag don't really help. Should she ask `How to listen to Mahler's 5th?` here, or is this SE not the place because this is considered opinion-based?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [musicfans.stackexchange.com](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) is better fit. Most, if not all, questions about music appreciation will be off-topic here.

A question like, "How does this symphony reflect the sonata-allegro form?" would be on-topic here, and that could be asked as part of music appreciation, but it's more clearly analysis.